# Adding data to default factories - laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have altered the default user model in laravel to include a username.
When I try and tinker with `factory(App\User::class)->create()` I get error saying that the username has not got a default value. How can I add this or alter the existing factory?

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: nothing, I tried to create and get error. cant find default factory in the doc

Comment: I mean can you share the new factory code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass in the fields you want to specify like this:

```
factory(App\User::class)->create([
     'username' => $user->name,
]);
```

Comment: @apokryfos It was my intention but I tape enter instead of delete and it publish it. I was trying to fast edit it but I'm too slow :') Thanks